# 'int' object is not subscriptable in lambda python

Tags: python, sorting, lambda

I have created a list of dict which I want to sort according to one element (Period) in the dict

```
T=dict()
def TaskGenerator(N):
    for i in range (0,N):
        ExcTime=randint(1,20)
        Period=randint(1,20)+ExcTime
        Uterlization=ExcTime/Period
        T[i]={'ID':i+1 , 'ExcTime' : ExcTime, 'Period' : Period, 'Uterlization':Uterlization}
    sorted(T,key=lambda x:x['Period'])
TaskGenerator(6)
```

However, It gives me an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\wei.du\Desktop\real-time\RMLS.py", line 33, in <module>
    TaskGenerator(6)
  File "C:\Users\wei.du\Desktop\real-time\RMLS.py", line 17, in TaskGenerator
sorted(T,key=lambda x:x['Period'])
  File "C:\Users\wei.du\Desktop\real-time\RMLS.py", line 17, in <lambda>
sorted(T,key=lambda x:x['Period'])
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

I think it means that in "sorted" function, in lambda function, "x" is an integer. But I do not really understand, isn't "x" an instant of T[i] (eg.T[1], which is of a dict type in python). why it complaints about "x" being an integer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you try to sort a `dict`, what you get is the keys. And since your keys are all integers, `sorted` tries to give you them in the correct order, according to your provided `key`. What you want, however, are the elements of the `dict` in a sorted order. To get the elements, you can use `T.values()`.

Using the values, the `TaskGenerator()` function will look like

```
from random import randint

T=dict()
def TaskGenerator(N):
    for i in range (0,N):
        ExcTime=randint(1,20)
        Period=randint(1,20)+ExcTime
        Uterlization=ExcTime/Period
        T[i]={'ID':i+1 , 'ExcTime' : ExcTime, 'Period' : Period, 'Uterlization':Uterlization}
    return sorted(T.values(), key=lambda x:x['Period'])
TaskGenerator(6)
```

Note that `T.values()` generates a new list of items and you must `return` that list to have a reference to it outside your function.

Comment: This works perfectly, However, I am still a bit confused, in the original code, I thought I was sorting a list of its element as dict type. instead of sorting a dict  Maybe I need to go through the basic about python again

Answer (score 3):

The iteration on a `dict` is on the keys, which are ints, which is not subscriptable (there is no `['Period']` on an int).

Also, you are not assigning the result of `sorted`. Try this instead:

```
sorted_values = sorted(T.values(), key=lambda x:x['Period'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to sort a dictionary, which is not possible. What you can do is use list instead.

```
def TaskGenerator(N):
    T=[]
    for i in range (0,N):
        ExcTime=randint(1,20)
        Period=randint(1,20)+ExcTime
        Uterlization=ExcTime/Period
        T.append({'ID':i+1 , 'ExcTime' : ExcTime, 'Period' : Period, 'Uterlization':Uterlization})
    print(T)
    T = sorted(T,key=lambda x:x['Period'])
    print(T)

TaskGenerator(6)
```

Sample Output:

```
[{'ID': 1, 'ExcTime': 17, 'Period': 35, 'Uterlization': 0.4857142857142857}, {'ID': 2, 'ExcTime': 9, 'Period': 29, 'Uterlization': 0.3103448275862069}, {'ID': 3, 'ExcTime': 1, 'Period': 8, 'Uterlization': 0.125}, {'ID': 4, 'ExcTime': 14, 'Period': 18, 'Uterlization': 0.7777777777777778}, {'ID': 5, 'ExcTime': 1, 'Period': 10, 'Uterlization': 0.1}, {'ID': 6, 'ExcTime': 7, 'Period': 8, 'Uterlization': 0.875}]
[{'ID': 3, 'ExcTime': 1, 'Period': 8, 'Uterlization': 0.125}, {'ID': 6, 'ExcTime': 7, 'Period': 8, 'Uterlization': 0.875}, {'ID': 5, 'ExcTime': 1, 'Period': 10, 'Uterlization': 0.1}, {'ID': 4, 'ExcTime': 14, 'Period': 18, 'Uterlization': 0.7777777777777778}, {'ID': 2, 'ExcTime': 9, 'Period': 29, 'Uterlization': 0.3103448275862069}, {'ID': 1, 'ExcTime': 17, 'Period': 35, 'Uterlization': 0.4857142857142857}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary has no specific ordering of elements.

One solution is to use `OrderedDict` from `collections`.

```
from random import randint
from collections import OrderedDict

T=dict()
def TaskGenerator(N):
    for i in range (0,N):
        ExcTime=randint(1,20)
        Period=randint(1,20)+ExcTime
        Uterlization=ExcTime/Period
        T[i]={'ID':i+1 , 'ExcTime' : ExcTime, 'Period' : Period, 'Uterlization':Uterlization}
    ordered = OrderedDict(sorted(T.items(), key=lambda i: i[1]['Period']))
    print(ordered)
TaskGenerator(6)

# OrderedDict([(5, {'ID': 6, 'ExcTime': 1, 'Period': 5, 'Uterlization': 0.20000000000000001}), 
#              (1, {'ID': 2, 'ExcTime': 5, 'Period': 15, 'Uterlization': 0.33333333333333331}),
#              (0, {'ID': 1, 'ExcTime': 2, 'Period': 17, 'Uterlization': 0.11764705882352941}), 
#              (4, {'ID': 5, 'ExcTime': 10, 'Period': 17, 'Uterlization': 0.58823529411764708}),
#              (2, {'ID': 3, 'ExcTime': 16, 'Period': 22, 'Uterlization': 0.72727272727272729}),
#              (3, {'ID': 4, 'ExcTime': 13, 'Period': 23, 'Uterlization': 0.56521739130434778})])
```